# What's wrong with my PC if a HDD stress test crashes it?

Tags: linux, ssd, freeze, crash

I noticed that recently my Linux PC has been crashing every few days. Everything just freezes and the CPU fan keeps running at a high speed. It happens during times of rather high CPU usage and disk I/O. It stays like that for hours until I notice it and hard reset the PC.

I think it might be a hardware problem since there is nothing in the system logs (journalctl), but I can't be sure.

At first I thought it might be overheating, but after cleaning out the dust and stress testing the CPU the temperatures and everything seemed fine.

Next I used the Linux `stress` tool. I noticed that the following command will crash my PC:

```
stress --hdd 4 -t 30s
```

So I suspected the SSD, but all SMART attributes and tests are fine.

What else could it be and how do I find out? Thank you very much in advance.

Some details about my PC:

- CPU: Intel Core i7-4770R, 4x 3.20GHz
- Chipset: Intel HM87
- SSD: Samsung SSD 840 PRO 256GB
- RAM: Corsair Vengeance SO-DIMM Kit 8GB, DDR3L-1600, CL9-9-9-24
- OS: Manjaro Linux

Comment: Possible cable problem.  Easy to find out.. just switch 'em out.  Otherwise, try unplugging the drive and boot from a linux live distro and run tests again.  You should be able to narrow down the cause.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thanks. Since it is a mini-PC (Zotac Zbox) there aren't any cables. I just took out the SSD and pushed it back in, the problem is still there. I don't know that booting to a live distro would help since stress testing the disk seems pointless without a disk.

Comment: Touche' sir! :)  Do you have another drive you can swap it out with the test at least of its the drive or the controller?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas That's a good idea, thanks. I'm sure my girlfriend won't miss the SSD in her laptop for a few minutes ;-): I'll see if I can try that out on the weekend.

Comment: Is there a BIOS drive test?  Or a bootable test separate from your OS?  Random link: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/570628/can-someone-recommend-a-good-bootable-hard-drive-diagnostic-utility/  At least then, you'll know if it's your OS?

Comment: @Openstar63 Also a great idea, thanks! I'll just boot from any Linux live distro and run the stress test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I booted a Live USB Linux system and the problem did not occur there. And after updating my Manjaro system to the latest recommended LTS kernel, my system no longer crashes during the stress test! I'll have to see if the problem is gone completely.

So it's definitely not a hardware problem and probably a kernel or I/O scheduler problem.

Thanks for the helpful comments!